# How to query list in memory instead of database call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I get list of `companies` from Database, each company might be parent to some another `company`, and I would like to find out which companies are having *childrens*. Nothing else, just `HasChildren` = `true` or `false`:

Getting companies from database:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CompDTO>> Get(SearchObject request)
{
  IQueryable<Company> companies;
  // .. some code where I'm fetching my companies
  return Map(companies);
}
```

Map method:

```
 private IEnumerable<CompDTO> Map(IEnumerable<Company> companies)
 {
      return companies.Select(c => Map(c));
 }
```

And another map method to create DTO objects from DB data:

```
private CompDTO Map(Company company)
{
    return new CompDTO()
    {
        Id = company.Id,
        CompanyName = company.Title,
        ParentCompanyId = company.ParentCompanyId,
        HasChildren = // I need to check here if company.Id is parent to any another company
    };
}
```

Basically I would like to check if my object has `childrens` or not so I might populate `HasChildren` property correctly. :)

P.S

I've tried with something like this:

```
private CompDTO Map(Company company)
{
    return new CompDTO()
    {
        Id = company.Id,
        CompanyName = company.Title,
        ParentCompanyId = company.ParentCompanyId,
        HasChildren = HasChildren(companyId).GetAwaiter().Result();
    };
}

private async Task<bool> HasChildren(long id)
{
    return await _context.Companies.AnyAsync(c => c.ParentCompanyId == id && c.ParentCompany.Active);
}
```

But with this approach I received error which says that *several threads share one database connection*
and anyway **I would like to avoid database call to check if company has childs or not** (true or false).
I guess its possible to do it here in memory? Because on many rows like 5000 there will be 5000 extra DB calls to check for true/false data :)

Thanks guys

Comment: You can use AsEnumerable().

Comment: @CetinBasoz But how to apply it in my example ?

Comment: Adding as an answer, would be a mess here.

Comment: You can do the self join query and return the result at once instead of checking the children by another database query in `HasChildren` method..

Comment: You are trying a join company to children, and you put the multithreading in just one table, not in the entire query ? This way you cannot use the capabilities of the SQL-Server. You enforce to read with millions of queries, synchronize it on the client, instead of using just one query.

Answer (score 1):

```
IQueryable<Company> companies = ctx.Companies;
var result = companies.AsEnumerable()
             .Select(c => new {
                c, HasChildren = companies.Any(cc => cc.parentCompanyId == c.Id)
             });
```

EDIT:

```
var companies = ctx.Companies.AsEnumerable();
var result = companies.Select(c => new CompDTO()
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        CompanyName = c.Title,
        ParentCompanyId = c.ParentCompanyId,
        HasChildren = companies.Any(cc => cc.ParentCompanyId == c.Id)
    });
```

Comment: this code would go in Get method? avoiding map etc? Because `HasChildren` property does not exist in `Company,` it exist only in `CompDTO` :)

Comment: @Roxy'Pro, HasChildren is a generated property. And also you are free to use a class for that instead of anonymous as I did (it was just a sample). Editing for you anyway.

Comment: Vote up mate! I figured it out but somehow solution almost identical to this led to another issue which is posted here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259143/how-to-solve-npgsql-npgsqloperationinprogressexception-a-command-is-already-in